# Running normal PHP scripts in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel

I am wanting to use a native php script in Laravel.

This is the script: https://github.com/SmItH197/SteamAuthentication

Basically it lets me log users in via Steam and then get their account details.

How could I go about integrating this? Would placing it in the public folder be an option? Surely thats a bad practice.

Im struggling with how to integrate it so i can use it in my views and the steam profile information in my controllers

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the structure of that plugin, I'd suggest you've got one of two options:

1) Take the code from that script and reimplement it in your own package(s) that you can then access from within Laravel through standard methods.

2) The Steam authentication is just an OpenID authentication (http://steamcommunity.com/dev), of which there are many libraries available for Laravel 5.

Here's a Laravel 4 implementation: https://github.com/Ehesp/Steam-Login - You may be able to use that as a starting point, or ask them nicely when they're going to upgrade to Laravel 5...

Comment: Thanks! Are there any guides on how I could go about doing number 1?

Comment: You're going to have to completely understand the code. There's also several ways you could implement this in Laravel 5, I'd suggest you create a package (http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/packages) as this would mean you could more easily use it on other applications.

Googling "Laravel packages" may give you more information on how to create the packages, but it's not going to tell you how to convert an existing php "script" to a Laravel Package.

Comment: thank you for your help. I've gone ahead and used this instead: http://packalyst.com/packages/package/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth working great :)

Comment: Nice one. I had a quick search but couldn't find a Laravel 5 one, obviously I didn't look hard enough!